# get array of object's first two keys as keys in new object and third key as array in that object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I have this data which is JSON I'm reading from a csv file. I want to be able to get Test, Result From all objects and for matching Test, Result in each object and have indicator array in it.

```
[{
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Alcohol abuse Liver Disease"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Congestive Heart Failure"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: NSAIDs"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: Lipid lowering drugs"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: Antibiotics"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: Histamine Blockers"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: Antifungals"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: anticonvulsants"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: antidepressants"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: testoserone"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "Low",
    "Indicator": "No concern"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "Low",
    "Indicator": "unlikely liver disease"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "Low",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: Oral contraceptives"
}, {
    "Test": "GGT",
    "Result": "Low",
    "Indicator": "Drugs: Clofibrate"
}, {
    "Test": "AST",
    "Result": "High",
    "Indicator": "(if >10xULN) acute hepatitis"
}]
```

I want to be able to parse it like

```
[
    {
        Test: "GGT",
        Result: "High",
        Indicators: [
            "Alcohol abuse Liver Disease",
            "Congestive Heart Failure",
            "Drugs: NSAIDs",
            "Drugs: Lipid lowering drugs",
            "Drugs: Antibiotics",
            "Drugs: Histamine Blockers",
        ],
    },
    {
        Test: "GGT",
        Result: "Low",
        Indicators: ["unlikely liver disease", "Drugs: Oral contraceptives", "Drugs: Clofibrate"],
    },
]
```

I skipped records in the result but I believe you get the idea. I want to map Test, Result Keys together and make an indicator array. Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the reducer function, so you can iterate over the array and return an array of new objects. In the reducer, you would want to inspect the accumulated array for an existing 'Result' property and then add the current 'Indicator' to that objects list.

See here for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

For me it would look something like this:

```
const list = [{a: 'v1', b: 'value'},{a: 'v2', b: 'value'},{a: 'v1', b: 'value2'}];

const result = list.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  const idx = accumulator.findIndex((item) => item.a == current.a);
  if(idx == -1) {
    accumulator.push({a: current.a, values: [current.b]});
    return accumulator;
  }
  accumulator[idx].values.push(current.b);
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been scratching my head for 12 hours. You are a lifesaver. Please upvote the question.